# Access to a oracle Database

Tags: oracle, permissions

I have created a database in Oracle. Say "TEMP" is the name of the database created. I have created a user DWH. Now I would like to grant access to TEMP for the user DWH.
How shall i do?

Comment: A database user is always created within a database. As long as the user has `CREATE SESSION` privilege, they have the ability to log into that database (and that database only).

Comment: Unless when you say "database", you're thinking of a schema? Is "TEMP" the name of a database instance or service, or is it the name of a schema?

Comment: @jeffrey kemp - TEMP is the name of a database

Answer (score 0):

. When you say you have created a user DWH do you mean at operating system level or database level ?If you have created a database user

Anyway the command for creating a user in database is

```
create user DWH identified by password;
```

Now if you want to be able to connect to database and create a table  you need the following

```
grant create session to DWH;
    alter user DWH default tablespace users quota 100m on users;
    grant create table to DWH;
```

You can grant other permissions also.You can also group permissions into a role and grant the role.

Comment: I mean DWH at database level. And what do you mean by operating system level?